# Can't set return value in batch file

Tags: function, batch-file, return, args

I'm trying to get a batch file containing a simple function that get parameter/s and return values. Actually i'm not able to do this!

**test.bat:**

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set arg=bar
echo my args %*
echo my new value %arg%

endlocal&set %~1=%arg%
```

**main.bat:**

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set var1=foo
echo Old value: %var1%
call test.bat %var1%
echo New value: %var1%
```

This is what the console return:

```
Old value: foo
my args: foo
my new value: bar
New value: foo
```

Comment: You could also use `CALL echo New value: %%%var1%%%`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `main.bat` you need to echo the value content of `%foo%` not the value content of `%var1%`:

Change:

```bat
echo New value: %var1%
```

To:

```bat
Echo New value: !%var1%!
```

Comment: That resolved my problem thanks you!
I don't get what ! or % mean, i'm trying to get comparison with * and & of c/c++ but i think i'm wrong!

Answer (score 1):

Your `main.bat` is passing `%var1%` to the `test` procedure as `%1`. `var1` has the value `foo` as demonstrated, so `%1` in `test` is `foo` hence `foo` will be modified to `bar`, not `var1`. Try `echo`ing %foo%, not `var1`